# Access an Oracle instance on AWS EC2 remotely

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services

I have a AWS EC2 instance on which I installed an Oracle DB: 11g.

All works fine if I access the DB from within the instance

```
sqlplus user/pwd@localhost/SERVICE
```

On the other hand if I change the "localhost" with the machine IP it does not allow access, even from within the machine.

The error is:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

I have already:

- Allowed access to port 1521 on the machine's firewall
- Added a rule for port 1521 from any IP on the AWS security group

By the way on the machine there is also a Tomcat server on a different port and by doing these two steps I can access that one fine from a browser on my laptop. So I believe that the networing is fine and it is the Oracle instance that is blocking the access. Any clues how to fix it?

Comment: By the way AWS RDS is not an option. The DB was previously on RDS and everything worked but for various reasons we want to manage it ourselves.

Comment: What URL are you using to hit your Oracle instance?

Comment: I tried both with the bare IP and with the DNS I created using Route53. In both cases it does not work. While the Tomcat on the same machine is reachable with both URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your listener.ora file that in my system is under:
`app/{User}/product/{dbversion}/dbhome_{someid}/network/admin`.

I added the line `(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521)))`.

After the modification my listener.ora looks like this. The other lines were there before and I left them there.

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

After the modificaiton you have to restart the service

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```